# jquery ui slider populating the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using jquery ui to set up some sliders.  I have many sliders, but I'm trying to minimize code.  Here is how I have the slider setup in html:

```
    <div class="budget_icon-wrapper">
        <div data-name="space_def" class="icon">
            <img class="info" src="images/info.png" />
            <img src="images/space-icon.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="space-item" class="space-item slider"></div>
        <div id="space_item-value" class="item-txt">$3.00</div>
    </div>
```

the div with a class of 'slider' is the slider.  In the div next to it I have different values for each slider, this happens to be 3 dollars.  What I'd like to do is pull the value out of that div (in this case 3) and have that be the value of the slider.

The script I tried but doesn't quite work is this:

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    value = parseInt($(this).siblings(".item-txt").text(),10);


    $(this).slider({
        animate: "fast",
        max: 25,
        min: 0,
        value: value,
        range: "min"
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: You gotta get rid of the `$` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
value = parseInt($(this).siblings(".item-txt").text(),10);
```

to

```
value = parseInt($(this).siblings(".item-txt").text().substring(1),10);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZJanK/)**

`parseInt` is returning `NaN` since the `$` is causing it to not return what you want. As the [docs on parseInt note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), "If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN."

Update: As requested, if you want the value of 3.00 just use `value = $(this).siblings(".item-txt").text().substring(1);`

Comment: so I was having a hard time totally understanding the function.  so parseInt if there was a decimal in the div it would make it a whole number.  What does the substring do, and what does putting the 1 in the () do?

Comment: parseInt will convert float or some strings to integers. Substring, in this case, is truncating $3.00 to 3.00 so parseInt can understand it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring for the specs on substring.

Comment: one last question.  Is there a way to use a decimal number, so if it was $3.30, the way it's set up right now it would store just 3 into the value variable right?  How would you get it to store 3.3?

Comment: You could use substring to remove the characters you don't need. Normally you need to convert the string to a float, but jQuery can take the string. Technically the parseInt isn't even really needed in your case above but you still need to remove the `$`.

Comment: hmmm, could you update the answer to keep the decimal?  This is still new territory for me and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: hey thanks so much for taking the time to explain all that and update answers, it's helpful for understanding it and seeing the differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    strVal = $(this).next('.item-txt').text().substring(1); // take the substring of the text "$3.00" from the second character to the end (remove the $)
    value = parseInt(strVal,10);
    $(this).slider({
        animate: "fast",
        max: 25,
        min: 0,
        value: value,
        range: "min"
    });
});
```